# Is there a method to disprove positive definiteness by finding an explicit $x$ such that $x'Ax=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

If a symmetric matrix $A$ is not positive definite, then there is at least one nonzero vector $x$ such that $x'Ax=0$.

Is there any method such that when given any symmetric matrix $A$ that is not positive definite (but may be positive semi-definite if needed) that explicitly finds at least one $x$ where $x'Ax=0$?

Comment: My suggestion: since $A$ is assumed to be symmetric, there exist $P$ and diagonal $\Lambda$ such that $P\Lambda P^{-1} = A$. Since $A$ is not positive definite, some of the elements of $\Lambda$ will be zero. Without loss of generality, assume these zeroes are ranked last on the diagonal. Then pick $x$ such that $P^{-1}x = $ a vector whose elements are zero except for the last element where there is a one. The difficulty is to find that vector. But you see, the problem depends on the choice of $A$; there exists no general solution

Answer (score 1):

Compute the null space. If it is not trivial, which it must not be if $A$ is only semi-definite, then any vector in the null space is a solution.

Comment: but "most" matrices are not  PSD or any kind of definite and question is only interesting when $A$ is non-singular.